# what is the problem with the first node in single linked list that doesn't give me the data

Tags: c

this is the full code: i hope if someone can help me for this problem

```
             #include <assert.h>
            #include <stddef.h>
            #include <stdio.h>
            #include <string.h>
            #include <ctype.h>
            #include <stdbool.h>
            #include <stdlib.h>
 

           
            struct word_count {
                char* word;
                int count;
                struct word_count* next;
            };
            
            /* Introduce a type name for the struct */
            typedef struct word_count WordCount;
            
            /* Global data structure tracking the words encountered */
            WordCount* word_counts = NULL;
            


            /* The maximum length of each word in a file */
            #define MAX_WORD_LEN 64
            void init_words(WordCount** wclist) {
                /* Initialize word count.  */
                wclist = NULL;
                //wclist = (WordCount*)malloc(sizeof(WordCount));
            }
```

at now i added this function to slove the problem :

```
            char* new_string(char* str) {
                return strcpy((char*)malloc(strlen(str) + 1), str);
            }
```

this function to add node to end of the list if the list doesn't empty

```
                void add_word(WordCount** wclist, char* word) {
                    WordCount* temp;
                    temp = (WordCount*)malloc(sizeof(WordCount));
                    if (temp == NULL) {
                        printf("error");
                        return;  
                    }
                    else {
                        temp->word = word; 
                        temp->count = 1;
                        temp->next = NULL;
                    }
            
                    if (*wclist == NULL)//the list is empty          
                        *wclist = temp;  //first node
                    else//this list is not empty
                    {
                            WordCount* p;
                            p = wclist; 
                            while ((p->next) != NULL) {
                
                                p = p->next;
                            }           
                            p->next = temp; //add new node to end of the list                
                   }    
                
                }
```

function to print the list:

```
            void printList(WordCount** wclist)
            {
                if(wclist==NULL)
                {
                    printf("empty");
                    return;
                }
                WordCount* wc = NULL;
                wc=wclist;
            
                while (wc != NULL)
                {
                    printf("[ %s | %d ]->", wc->word, wc->count);
                    wc = wc->next;
                }
            }
```

this is the main:

```
            int main()
            {
                init_words(&word_counts);
            
                char* strings[] = { "abc","def","aaa","bbb","zzz","aaa" };
                add_word(&word_counts, strings[0]);   
                add_word(&word_counts, strings[1]);
                add_word(&word_counts, strings[2]); 
                add_word(&word_counts, strings[3]);
                add_word(&word_counts, strings[4]);
                add_word(&word_counts, strings[5]);
                printList(&word_counts);
            
            }
```

For example when I insert the words to the list the first node doesn't appear

```
            input:
            > "abc" "def" "aaa" "bbb" "zzz" "aaa" 
            
            the output:
            
            > [ X{δ | 1 ]->[ def | 1 ]->[ aaa | 1 ]
```

Comment: First error: In `init_words`, the line `wclist = NULL;` should be `*wclist = NULL;`

Comment: In `print_list` this is wrong `wc=wclist;`. The compiler should give you a warning there as the types are incompatible. Don't ignore warnings! Fix them all before posting any question on Stack Overflow. It should be `wc=*wclist;`

Comment: thank you very much for your help